# I am trying to make multiple arrays using the following syntax, however it makes one array which is replaced on each iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the following syntax to try and make multiple arrays with the name TravelPlanSingle'index'. Instead of making multiple arrays I get one array which is replaced over and over as the index is updated. I am not very comfortable with Javascript syntax. Is my syntax incorrect, or do I have another issue?

```
 scope.hiddenEvents["travelPlanSingle"+i] = tpArray;
```

Comment: You really should post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If "tpArray" is itself really an array instance, then what's probably happening is that you're overwriting the array. All of your "hiddenEvents" will point to the same one.

You can avoid that by explicitly making a copy:

```
scope.hiddenEvents["travelPlanSingle"+i] = tpArray.slice(0);
```

Now understand that that's a *shallow* copy of the array. If you need more than a shallow copy, things get more involved.